# use router in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create some basic express application. I want to use routers in it.
SO I created router.js where it has

```
router.route('/a/x').post(x.p)
router.route('/a/y').post(x.p)
router.route('/a/z').post(x.p)
```

Now I want to load the router to my index.js

```
var routes = require('./router.js')
app.use(?,routes)
```

I am wondering what to keep in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you imported your `router.js` in the index, you need to tell `express` it can use this router.

In the following, I assume you used `var router = require('express').Router;` in order to create your own router.

But first, did you export the router?

```
// In router.js
var router = require('express').Router;

router.route('/a/x').post(x.p)
router.route('/a/y').post(x.p)
router.route('/a/z').post(x.p)

module.exports = router; // This line may differ in funtion of your Node.js version
```

And to use it:

```
// In your index.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = require('./router.js');

app.use('/', router);
```

I encourage your to read the [documentation of `app.use()` using router as a valid middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
const Express = require(`express`);
const App = Express();
require(`./router.js`)(App);
```

Hope it solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

In **app.use** first param, you can specify any prefix of the route.

```
import * as express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/a/x', (req, res) => {
    // Your code
});

**OR**

var router = require('./router.js')


app.use('/v1', router); // HERE you can specify version if you want or / for nothing
```